# Getting all registered subclasses of an ABCMeta

Tags: python-3.x, subclass, abstract-base-class

I have a directory structure similar to the following:

```
.
├── main.py
├── model.py
└── models
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── model_a.py
    └── model_b.py
```

`model.py` contains an Abstract Base Class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass
```

in the `models`folder are two implementations of this base class, `model_a.py` and `model_b.py`, who register themselves to the main `Base`class.  `model_a.py` looks like this:

```
from model import Base

class ModelA(Base):

    def run(self):
        return "a"

ModelA.register(Base)

assert issubclass(ModelA, Base)
```

and `model_b.py`is similar.

Now, what I am trying to do in `main.py` is to create a dictionary of all the subclasses of `Base` so that I can select one (via the GUI of my program) and run it:

```
from model import Base

subclasses = Base.__subclasses__()

dct = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in subclasses}

klass = dct['ModelA']
klass.run()
```

But I can't get it to work. I get `RuntimeError: Refusing to create an inheritance cycle`when I try to execute one of the derived classes and the dictionary in `main.py` is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realise this is rather late, but in case it's helpful to anyone else who stumbles upon this...

You've got a few problems here:

1. Your classes are the wrong way round in that `register` call; it would only make sense in this context to call `Base.register(ModelA)` (not the other way round) in order to register `ModelA` as a "[virtual subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register)" of `Base`.
2. Calling `ModelA.register(Base)` is trying to register `Base` as a virtual subclass of `ModelA`, but `ModelA` is already an actual subclass of `Base`, - which is why you're getting an inheritance cycle. You can't have classes X and Y inheriting from each other.
3. However, as `ModelA` is explicitly a subclass of `Base`, you don't need to call `register` at all.  You want either:

   ```py
   class ModelA(Base):
      ...
   ```

   with no `register` call (here `ModelA` is an actual subclass of `Base`), or:

   ```py
   class ModelA:
       ...

   Base.register(ModelA)
   ```

   (here `ModelA` is a standalone class, outside `Base`'s inheritance hierarchy, but it is registered as a virtual subclass). Either/or - not both.

   In either case, `issubclass(ModelA, Base)` would be `True`.
4. `__subclasses__()` doesn't pick up virtual subclasses, only actual ones - so if you want to use that, you should forget about `register()` and just make `ModelA` a real subclass of `Base` (the first option above).

   (This is, to my mind, a wart with the whole ABC/`register` mechanism: `issubclass()` might be `True` but `__subclasses__()` doesn't pick it up - nasty.)
5. If you don't import the model containing `ModelA` at *some* point in your execution, it's never set up so `ModelA` won't show up in `Base.__subclassess__()` anyway. This is probably why the dictionary in `main.py` is empty.

   A fix would be to add a line to `main.py` saying `import models`, and have `models/__init__.py` import `model_a` and `model_b`. Then when `main` runs, it imports `models`, which in turn imports `model_a` and `model_a`, executing the definitions of `ModelA` and `ModelB` and adding them to `Base`'s class hierarchy.
6. On your final line, you don't instantiate an instance of whatever class `klass` is pointing at; the line should be:

   ```py
   klass().run()
   ```